# Ternary expression validating type field in WHERE clause T-Sql

Tags: mysql, sql-server

The title is not really explicit so let me clear up :

I have a table which looks like this :

```
ID    NAME    EXTID
===================
1     xxxx    1
-------------------
2     aaaa    2
-------------------
3     dddd    ENTR
-------------------
4     ssss    4
```

- **ID** : int
- **NAME** : varchar(50)
- **EXTID** : varchar(50)

My web apps let the user insert rows. When inserting, the user should precise a name. Then, an `ID` is created, and I set to the column `EXTID`, which is an external ID, the same value as column `ID`. Then, the user can change the `EXTID` in the future (for synchronization purposes, but let not fall in useless explaination).

**THE PROBLEM :**

I would like to get all records that have the same `ID` and `EXTID` value. I tryied the following query :

```
SELECT  T.*
FROM    myTable T
WHERE   T.ID = T.EXTID
```

But I got the following error :

> Failed to convert the varchar value 'ENTR' in the int data type .

So my **question** is : is it possible to create a ternary expression like this :

```
SELECT   T.*
FROM     myTable T
WHERE    T.ID = (ISNUMERIC(T.EXTID) ? CAST(T.EXTID AS int) : -1)
```

-1 to display no rows in the case the cast would fail.

Comment: why not convert the int to a `varchar(50)`?

Comment: It works well ! Could you please answer ? And so the ternary expression doesn't exist in Sql or T-Sql ?

Comment: I think the logic you were trying to apply would be a case statement: `CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(T.EXTID)=1 THEN CAST(T.EXTID AS int) ELSE -1 END` however that could still yield wrong results as `isnumeric()` doesn't mean proper conversion to int is possible, IE `1.5`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This explicit cast will allow the conversion to go the other way instead of trying to convert non-numeric values to int implicitly.

```
SELECT  T.*
FROM    myTable T
WHERE   CAST(T.ID as varchar(50)) = T.EXTID
```